# Form Input Hover With onClick

Tags: javascript, html

We are trying to use image mapping on a form input element while combining a mouse over (hover) on the image map.

We have a Javascript function to change the background and it works fine. And when we use an onclick function to replace the background image, this works fine too.

But as soon as the mouse moves away, the mouse over event calls again and the image background changes during onclick event, reverting back to original image.

Here is the url:
https://s45dev.com/spavie/treatment-planner/man/#gf_2

1.) Click on FACE, then NEXT button.
2.) Click on FOREHEAD.

You will see the orange region now as our mapping area. What we are trying to do is select a region on the face AND still have the hover work to illustrate the other regions when choosing.

Here is our HTML:

```
<img id="Woman-Face" src="https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face.jpg" border="0" width="357" height="329" orgWidth="357" orgHeight="329" usemap="#image-face-map" alt="" />
<map name="image-face-map" id="ImageMapsCom-image-face-map">
<area shape="rect" coords="355,327,357,329" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="javascript:;" />
<area id="Woman-Forehead" alt="Forehead" title="Forehead" href="javascript:;" shape="poly" coords="77,125,76,117,76,108,78,96,87,85,97,76,106,76,114,78,127,72,141,71,150,76,159,82,166,92,174,100,182,110,163,114,130,122,112,122,95,122,84,120" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="wff_select();" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Woman-Face').src= 'https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face-forehead.jpg';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Woman-Face').src= 'https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face.jpg';"  />
<area id="Woman-Eyes" alt="Eyes" title="Eyes" href="javascript:;" shape="poly" coords="75,145,80,133,100,128,114,132,126,132,137,132,144,127,165,122,180,122,189,127,194,136,190,142,175,147,148,145,133,145,119,145,109,149,102,155,92,156,81,158" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="wfe_select();" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Woman-Face').src= 'https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face-eyes.jpg';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Woman-Face').src= 'https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face.jpg';"  />
<area id="Woman-Lower" alt="Lower Face" title="Lower Face" href="javascript:;" shape="poly" coords="86,192,95,187,110,187,131,184,148,180,163,179,185,176,201,172,205,187,197,199,191,210,182,220,172,228,164,234,156,240,152,244,132,247,119,241,94,211" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="wfl_select();" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Woman-Face').src= 'https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face-lower.jpg';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Woman-Face').src= 'https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face.jpg';"  />
</map>
```

And, here is the javascript:

```
function wff_select(){
jQuery('#choice_2_26_0').attr('checked', true);
if(document.images) document.getElementById('Woman-Face').src='https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face-forehead.jpg';
}
function wfe_select(){
jQuery('#choice_2_26_1').attr('checked', true);
if(document.images) document.getElementById('Woman-Face').src= 'https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face-eyes.jpg';
}
function wfl_select(){
jQuery('#choice_2_26_2').attr('checked', true);
if(document.images) document.getElementById('Woman-Face').src= 'https://s45dev.com/spavie/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/woman-face-lower.jpg';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On your website, I don't see any orange illustration when I mouse over any of the areas on the face, only when I click on the parts of the face. The CSS hover selector can make it so the objects are always highlighted when moused over.

You can use the CSS :hover selector like this:

```
#object{
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#object:hover
{
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px gray;
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/buLqsxm2/7/)

You could change it to be an image or something like that in order to work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand problem but You do not use AJAX so cookies will be best way to "remember" changes and load them after page reload.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Because I do not know what language do You use on server side.